# downgrade chef-client version 11

Tags: knife, cookbook, chef-infra

trying to downgrade `chef-client`. enclosed a snippet:

```
$ chef-client --version
Chef: 11.10.4

$ curl -sL https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -v 11.8.2
Downloading Chef 11.8.2 for ubuntu...
downloading https://www.opscode.com/chef/metadata?v=11.8.2&prerelease=false&nightlies=false&p=ubuntu&pv=12.04&m=x86_64
  to file /tmp/install.sh.1934/metadata.txt
trying wget...
url https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/chef_11.8.2-1.ubuntu.12.04_amd64.deb
md5 3d3b3662830a44eeec71aadc098a4018
sha256  a5b00a24e68e29a01c7ab9de5cdaf0cc9fd1c889599ad9af70293e5b4de8615c
downloaded metadata file looks valid...
downloading https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/chef_11.8.2-1.ubuntu.12.04_amd64.deb
  to file /tmp/install.sh.1934/chef_11.8.2-1.ubuntu.12.04_amd64.deb
trying wget...
Comparing checksum with sha256sum...
Installing Chef 11.8.2
installing with dpkg...
(Reading database ... 107385 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace chef 11.8.2-1.ubuntu.12.04 (using .../chef_11.8.2-1.ubuntu.12.04_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement chef ...
Setting up chef (11.8.2-1.ubuntu.12.04) ...
Thank you for installing Chef!

$ chef-client --version
Chef: 11.10.4
```

also tried rebooting the machine, though there result is the same.

can it be done, can `chef-client` be downgraded?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Chef `11.10.4` from the omnibus installer (basically the same `install.sh`  you are using for the older version) then you basically got a self-contained installation of Chef inside `/opt/chef`.

Removing that directory will remove almost all traces of the old install. All that is left is to remove the symlinks inside `/usr/bin`, which will probably be `chef-client`, `chef-solo`, `chef-shell`, `knife`, `ohai` and maybe a few others (look for symlinked files in `/usr/bin` that point to `/opt/chef`.

After that, reinstall using your above technique and you should have the correct version installed.

Comment: Another option is to use the purge command associated with your underlying package installer (eg apt-get) this might do this automatically and make things cleaner.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, `dpkg --purge chef` will not do so, since `dpkg-query -L chef` does not hold all the file records.

Answer (score 0):

Just install specific version from https://downloads.chef.io/chef (depends on your OS). I succeeded to downgrade my chef-client version with simple installation that override the newer one.